# Can a class have its own method outside of an interface under DI?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, interface

I have been reading about DI and autowiring some objects in Spring and came across this situation - Classes A and B implement interface I. Class C gets an autowired dependency of type I - i.e. an object of A or B. Inteface I has methods m1 and m2 which are implemented by both A and B - which C can now invoke. What if, A has its own method m3 and B has its own method m4 - m3 and m4 are not part of I. I am unable to allow C to invoke these. Is there a workaround this? If not, is there a design principle which is against this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem since there is no sample code.  Here is my answer from what I do understand.  I don't think you can invoke a method of an instance that is injected into your object via an interface unless the method is in the contract.  It beats the whole purpose of using interfaces.  You can only use what is defined in the interface.  If your class implementing that interface have additional methods, the only way I can think of calling them is via some reflection magic.  But then, that would be going against patterns and best practices.